# Alternative replacement cable for classic sturmy archer 3 speed shifter?

Tags: replacement, cable

I have classic sturmy archer 3 speed trigger with a snapped cable.
Unfortunaly, these aparently need special cables (endings) http://www.sturmey-archer.com/en/products/detail/classic-trigger

Do I need to replace the cable exactly with such one again (It's really expensive by now for a simple cable) or is there a fitting alternative or trick to avoid spending 50$ for a simple unprotected steel cable?
Does anyone have any experience with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I was on a budget I'd go for the combination of the following two products (I'm not affiliated with this particular webshop):

[Elvedes: 6451-3M](https://www.giga-bikes.nl/22067-elvedes-versnellingskabel-sturmey-archer-3-meter-6451-3m/) - derailleur cable, €1.15
[TOM adjustment nipple Sturmey Archer](https://www.giga-bikes.nl/165299-amigo-stelnippel-sturmey-archer-zilver/) - adjustment nipple, €1.25

It doesn't look as nice as the original, still remains functional.

For US customers:
[Cable anchor](https://www.bicyclehero.com/us/sturmey-archer-cable-fix-adjustor-anchor-hub-part-3sp.html) - $4.25
The cable itself still needs to be found.

Comment: The Elvedes is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Article costs 1€, with shipping and customs = 60 €??!?!? I'll guess I'll look for a local vintage bicycle dealer :)

Comment: @HerrDerb, what is your location? If you need my help, I can order the items (less than €5 shipping) and put in an envelope (another €10 I guess, depending on location). Or search the internet for "Sturmey Archer cable anchor".